# Laravel blade templating stop master layout from reloading

Tags: templates, laravel, laravel-blade

my question is:
"How to stop the master template/layout from reloading?"

Like, when i make a navigation bar and i click on a link to a different view that extends master
the whole page reloads. Instead i'd just like the  section "content" to reload and have "master" stay put.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
g3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) (pushState + AJAX). It's a jQuery plugin that provides functionality to switch out blocks of content, plus update the location bar URL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are some ways to do that, but it's not really on Laravel you should focus, but in HTML: one way would be to develop an ajax site, where your layout is loaded once and the content is loaded via ajax.

I just bought this ajax template for an admin panel: http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0573SK0. Click to remove the frame and look how it feels nice.